# What is a hump function?

Tags: calculus

I have been in trouble with the hump function(s)
What are them?

Could you give me an explicit formula for "Hump"(not bump) function.

Thanks

Comment: The mathematician's fetish equivalent of [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/r7uor/my_friend_built_a_robot_pig_for_him_to_have_sex/)? Or more seriously: [A function used in optimisation](http://www-optima.amp.i.kyoto-u.ac.jp/member/student/hedar/Hedar_files/TestGO_files/Page1621.htm)?

Comment: Could you tell us about the context in which you came across the term "hump" function? Is it possible someone *meant* bump function but said "hump"? You could have also included the problem behind this: "find a $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ function with analyticity set $\emptyset$" ([on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/91894/what-is-a-hump-function), if that is indeed you).

Comment: @anon, that is exactly the context I was asked this question.

Comment: Tolstov uses the word "hump" [here](http://books.google.si/books?id=XqqNDQeLfAkC&pg=PA84&lpg=PA84&dq=hump+function+tolstov+fourier+series&source=bl&ots=dPTgIus3Nq&sig=L_lcy0gTn4g-jZ0AxTAe8Vv82ro&hl=sl&sa=X&ei=wwtrT8-6GIOVswan9PCKAg&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false). I thought it might be related.

Comment: Often the two names are used for the same thing.

Comment: In my neighbourhood there are speed humps. I have never understood the difference.

Comment: MATLAB has something called the `humps()` function which it uses for demonstrating quadrature, optimization, and rootfinding routines.

Comment: With either name, it would seem something climactic is happening in a short interval of time.

Answer (score 3):

i think any function $g(x)$ that is the derivative of a [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function#Examples)

$$ g(x) = f'(x) $$

where $f(x)$ may be any of the functions shown as examples of an S-shaped sigmoid function indicated in the Wikipedia article, **any** of those can be legitimately called a *"hump function"*.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the category of functions called *humps* that I'm familiar with, then of one these functions is $f$ defined below (try plotting it for $x \in [-2, 8]$, so that $f(x) \in [0, 25]$).

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{(x-3)^2+0.1} + \frac{1}{(x-2)^2+0.05} + 2$$

Comment: and to reference @J. M. isn't a mathematician's point, I do think the name comes from MATLAB.

Comment: see: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/function-functions.html#zmw57dd0e8359

Answer (score 0):

There are many a hump functions (so-called kernel functions): [see the wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics)).

The functions in examples above are not compact, i.e. for all $x\in(-\infty, \infty),\;\, f(x) \not= 0.$

If you want a compact function, where non-zero value is defined only in a line segment:
$$
f(x)= 
\begin{cases}
\frac{(\Delta^2 - x^2)^3}{\Delta},\quad |x|<\Delta\\
0, \quad\quad\quad\;\;\,|x|\geq \Delta.
\end{cases}
$$
This function has continuous derivatives. Therefore, it $f(x)$ is a smooth function.